# Как найти точки пересечения касательной одной окружности с другой

Tags: математика, геометрия

Провожу касательную от точки A по окружности B (вычисляю ее через пересечение с окружностью С), получаю координаты D, E. Как найти точки F и G? Радиус окружности выделенной пунктиром (на ней лежат точки F и G) так же известен. Большая окружность выделенная жирным пунктиром тоже имеет центр в точке A

Какая формула используется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используется такая формула, что треугольник, вписанный в окружность и опирающийся на ее диаметр - прямоугольный.

Comment: @igor можете сказать как это использовать?

Answer (score 3):

Треугольник `ABD` - прямоугольный. Вы знаете радиус окружности `B` и длину `AD`, то есть можете найти любой угол в `ABD` и координаты точки `D`. Если считать, что начало координат в точке `А`, то координаты точки `F`, пропорциональны координатам точки `D`, c коэффициентом `|AF|/|AD|`.

Comment: точно все сказано

Comment: ABD не образуют прямой угол! точка D это касательная от точки А к окружности В и эта точка будет всегда меняться в зависимости от расстояния

Comment: точка меняется и угол AD относительно AB меняется тоже,  и всегда  угол ADB будет прямым

Comment: @eSkry Касательная к окружности всегда перпендикулярна радиусу, проведенному к точке касания. Eвклид был не фраер.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю идти через векторы. 
Ниже используется прямоугольная декартова система координат с началом в точке `A(0; 0)`, горизонтальной осью `Ax` и вертикальной осью `Ay`.

Вектор `АF = k` вектора `AD`. Вектор `АG = k` вектора `AE`.

Вектор `AD = (xD - xA; yD - yA) = (xD, yD`). Вектор `AE = (xE - xA, yE - yA) = (xE, yE)`.

Коэффициент пропорциональности `k` равен отношению длин векторов `AF` и `AD`, где длина `AF` равна известному радиусу `R` окружности, изображенной жирным пунктиром. А длина вектора `AD` равна корню квадратному из суммы квадратов координат этого вектора, то есть длина `AD = (xD^2 + yD^2)^0.5`.

Зная `k`, находим `AF = (k*xD; k*yD)`.

Зная координаты вектора AF и координаты его начала А можно найти координаты его конца, сложив соответствующие координаты вектора и начала. Учитывая, что начало вектора совпадает с началом координат, заключаем, что точка `F` имеет координаты `(k*xD; k*yD)`, где `k=R/(xD^2 + yD^2)^0.5`

Аналогично `G` имеет координаты `(k*xG, k*yG)`.

Comment: Я что-то не вижу, где объяснения как найти `xD` и `yD`.

Comment: @Igor Вопрошающий в вопросе указывает "получаю координаты D, E". Соответственно это не спрашивается. Исхожу из того, что это известно.

Comment: Логично. Интересно, как он находит координаты точки `D`, не считая треугольник `ABD` прямоугольным.

Comment: @Igor Из его слов можно предположить, что он решает систему уравнений, состоящую из уравнений двух окружностей (с центром в точках B и D соответственно).